# Exception on the pods java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: HTT

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

```
    <hz:properties>
        .
        .    
            <hz:property name="service-label-name">
                  ${com.app.hazelcast.service.label.name:app}
            </hz:property>
            <hz:property name="service-label-value">
                  ${com.app.hazelcast.service.label.value:app}             
            </hz:property>
    </hz:properties>
    <hz:join>
          <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
          <hz:tcp-ip enabled="false">
<hz:members>${com.test.app.hazelcast.network.members:127.0.0.1}</hz:members>
          </hz:tcp-ip>
          <hz:kubernetes enabled="true" />
    </hz:join>
```

When I am running the pod I am getting below error:-

```
28-Jun-2021 07:37:43.404 WARNING [hz.distributedCacheInstance.IO.thread-in-0] com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection.null [10.84.0.139]:5701 [cxth-cache-runtime] [4.2] Connection[id=51, /10.84.0.139:54029->/10.84.0.108:8080, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.84.0.108]:8080, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=51, /10.84.0.139:54029->/10.84.0.108:8080, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.84.0.108]:8080, alive=true, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.distributedCacheInstance.IO.thread-in-0
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: HTT
                at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:117)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:383)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:368)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:294)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.executeRun(NioThread.java:249)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
28-Jun-2021 07:37:43.804 WARNING [hz.distributedCacheInstance.IO.thread-in-1] com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection.null [10.84.0.139]:5701 [cxth-cache-runtime] [4.2] Connection[id=54, /10.84.0.139:35779->/10.84.0.108:8080, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.84.0.108]:8080, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=54, /10.84.0.139:35779->/10.84.0.108:8080, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.84.0.108]:8080, alive=true, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.distributedCacheInstance.IO.thread-in-1
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: HTT
                at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:117)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:383)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:368)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:294)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.executeRun(NioThread.java:249)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
28-Jun-2021 07:37:43.804 WARNING [hz.distributedCacheInstance.IO.thread-in-2] com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection.null [10.84.0.139]:5701 [cxth-cache-runtime] [4.2] Connection[id=53, /10.84.0.139:54853->/10.84.0.109:8080, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.84.0.109]:8080, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=53, /10.84.0.139:54853->/10.84.0.109:8080, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.84.0.109]:8080, alive=true, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.distributedCacheInstance.IO.thread-in-2
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: HTT
                at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:117)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:383)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:368)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:294)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.executeRun(NioThread.java:249)
                at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
```

Why my pod is trying to communicate to port 8080. How to resolve this issue?
I have added the **service-label-name** and **service-label-value** property but, still I didn't get any success.

Is there any problem with my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Please set `service-port` to `5701` in order to avoid Hazelcast communicating with `8080`.

Read more at [Hazelcast Kubernetes: Hazelcast Configuration](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#hazelcast-configuration).

Comment: I have tried the service-port also, but I am still getting same issue. here is my configuration:- <hz:property name="service-name">app-service</hz:property>
<hz:property name="service-port">5701</hz:property>

Comment: I think the properties should be inside the section `<hz:kubernetes>`

Comment: I have tried to add property inside <hz:kubernetes> but I  get "Element 'hz:kubernetes' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty."